# LowLevelKeyboardProc being called for elevated applications when run as non-elevated

Tags: winapi, keyboard-hook, setwindowshookex

My application is run as the current user **without** admin privileges. It then installs a keyboard hook to catch key events using `SetWindowsHookEx` with `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` (not the DLL injection one). It works fine for keystrokes into a fellow non-admin window however it doesn't catch any for a window that was run as administrator. I would like it to work for both.

From a security perspective, I suppose this makes sense, however it's quite annoying that this crept up on me (couldn't find anything indicating this in the WinAPI docs). Is there any way I can mitigate this without having to run my application as administrator? Also, would the main alternative, **RawInputAPI** still have this problem?

Comment: Depending on what you are really trying to accomplish, it may well be that [RegisterHotKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey) is the alternative you are looking for.

Comment: UIPI ensures this can't work.  The lesser-known sibling of UAC, User Interface Privilege Isolation prevents a non-elevated app from hijacking the capabilities of an elevated one.  Imagine an unelevated app clicking buttons in Task Manager.  Making this work requires a manifest with uiAccess=true, code-signed with a valid certificate and stored in a protected directory, like c:\program files.  Note how that still involves a security check, just once, the user has to agree to you installing the program there.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Interface_Privilege_Isolation

Comment: @IInspectable `RegisterHotKey` still seems to use the same message loop mechanism to insert the keys into my program. Are you sure this will work for keys sent to admin program?

Comment: @HansPassant Your solution seems to be correct (although I've hit some other issues by using `uiAccess` which I'll have to ask another question for).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hans Passant's suggestion is the best answer I can find. That is, to specify `uiAccess="true"` in the app.manifest which appears to work once you get the requirements in place (signed app, protected directory).

Unfortunately there's another problem which is how do I start the app from another signed app with `uiAccess`. This is a separate question here:

[Is it possible to start a process with uiAccess=true from another process with uiAccess=true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52731727/is-it-possible-to-start-a-process-with-uiaccess-true-from-another-process-with-u)