# Is it possible to start a process with uiAccess=true from another process with uiAccess=true

Tags: c#, process, manifest, windows-process

A process is already running that has `uiAccess=true` in it's manifest. Is it possible for this program to start another such process with `uiAccess=true`? Currently, whenever `Process.Start` is called for the second process a `Win32Exception` is thrown with message:

> The requested operation requires elevation

Running the first process as Administrator stops the failure however this is not an option for me.

I know it is possible to do this from a service using `SetTokenInformation` etc. (and I'm already doing this) but that's as user Local System so I'm presuming is not reusable.